# main thread load tensorflow model, used in child thread error

Tags: python, tensorflow

main thread load tensorflow model, used in child thread error.

I create two thread, one is main thread, is used for load model,

then create child thread, and pass load model return value to child thread。

But，when child thread use the parameter to do inference